# UML Model and Diagram definition, where? – XMI has them, Standards not?

Tags: uml, xmi

So, I’ve been looking through the UML 2.3 Infrastructure, UML 2.3 Superstructure, MOF 2.0 and XMI 2.11 standards in search of the specification and definition of Models and Diagrams.

I am aware about models and diagrams and what they are (diagrams show a view on the model), but seeing them in an XMI file exported from Visual Paradigm and analysing it I got a bit confused.

Throughout the standards mentioned above the specification mentions diagrams and models specifically with their corresponding meanings, but I could not find where it is defined, nor, the most important part, how it comes in to the UML Metamodel.

XMI mentioned above has the following structure (heavily pruned):

```
<xmi:XMI xmi:version="2.1" …>
  <uml:Model />
  <uml:Diagram />
</xmi:XMI>
```

So as I could not find definitions on Model and Diagram, I could also not find out how many Model elements are allowed/possible and what content it may have. Same for Diagrams, although I know those can be `0..*`.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. I am not sure model vs. diagram is something specific to UML, so I am not usre if it should be specified in the standard. There are special standards for diagrams on the OMG site.

Comment: It may not be specific to UML, but UML has both and differentiates between the 2. Thus, it should be defined somewhere for UML.

Comment: Especially when they are elements of the Metamodel which are serialised with XMI.

Answer (score 0):

THe easiest way to check your model is to use the EclipseUML2 editor. This is not a graphical UML but a tree where you can create elements directly on the XMI model. The XMI is 2.1 corresponding to UML 2.3 and is really clean.
This XMI is used by RSA IBM, Topcased, Papyrus at project level and you can even have multiple projects merge with Omondo. Really cool !!

Comment: I’m not looking into inspecting XMI data. I want to know the definition of how Model and Diagram come in to XMI.

Comment: You need to transform your database into java code. I recommend the Eclipse Dali project to do it. Once you get the code with java annotations representing Database information into the code you can reverse your code in order to get an UML Model. Pretty good free reverse with Topcased, but all association and annotations are not reversed which is a problem if you look at mapping database keys on attributs ! I use EclipseUML Omondo and get the annotation translated into my UML Model and all keys on attributes. Really marvellous but very very expensive, so for testing open source is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Models tags are used in XMI files. I'm not sure there's a standard for that (in the sense that sometimes you just see a single model tag for the whole XMI and other times tools seem to open a new model tag for each diagram.

What it is true is that we don't have yet a standard to store in an XML file the diagram information (layout, sizes,...). There is [some work in progress](http://modeling-languages.com/blog/content/anybody-remembers-uml-diagram-interchange-format) but right now each tool uses its own proprietary format for that (some of them store the info in the same XMI as the model information others do it in a separate file).

Comment: Visual paradigm places the Model tag in the uml namespace in the XMI. Going by that it should be defined in UML … Unfortunately, it is not … (did not find it). Thanks for the info on diagrams. UMLDI is diagram specific though (how to represent individual diagrams and its contents), which still leaves the problem on why and where there is Model and Diagram, and how they should be mapped to/from an XMI.